# What is total executable lines in emma code coverage report

Tags: code-coverage, emma

I have a file like this reported from Emma.

OVERALL COVERAGE SUMMARY:

[class, %]  [method, %] [block, %]  [line, %]   [name]
6%   (2/33)!    3%   (4/150)!   1%   (48/4378)! 1%   (11.8/799)!    all classes

OVERALL STATS SUMMARY:

total packages: 2
total classes:  33
total methods:  150
total executable files: 18
total executable lines: 799

As you can see, EMMA does not report SLOC, instead it says total executable lines:  799. What exactly is executable lines?

Answer (score 0):

SLOC includes blank lines and comments too. Emma reports code coverage on the lines that contain code only, i.e executable lines of code.